# Linking a button to a XML page

Tags: java, android

Basic question but i have checked a number of places and can only find information on pop up messages like toast etc.

How would I be able to link buttonA (stored in fragment xml file) so that it will view activitypage.xml?

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by view the activity's xml?

Comment: @A--C I have just used made-up values for this example but i essentially mean how can i link a button on one xml screen to another xml screen so it will open up another screen when clicked

Comment: If you define each "screen" as a new `Activity`, something like my answer should help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can do make a new Activity for each "Screen". Let's make an example, MyNewActivity. The rest is pretty simple. In your button XML add this line:

```
android:onClick = "nextActivity"
```

Then in the Fragment that has contains buttonA, do something like this:

```
public void nextActivity (View v)
{
  Intent intent = new Intent (getActivity(), MyNewActivity.class); //using getActivity since this is from a fragment
  getActivity().startActivity (intent);
}
```

make sure that in MyNewActivity you put this line in `onCreate`

```
setContentView(R.layout.activitypage);
```

Comment: Really confused now, maybe because i have an action bar as well.
This is the java code which contains the fragments.
http://pastebin.com/7zBTv5W9

Where would i place the string of code?
Also which part of the code is the part which references the screen i want viewed?

Comment: You have a ViewPager, is that what you mean by screens? You also have many, many fragments there...

Answer (score 0):

In your `Activity` which inflates your button implement a method to open the desired second `Activity` when the button is clicked. Either `button.setOnClickListener()` of a method declared in the `xml` for the button under the `android:onClick="buttonClick"` attribute.